# SSIS import all Paradox tables into SQL Server 2012

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssis, paradox

Writing my first SSIS package in VS 2012 and have managed to get it to connect to he Paradox tables without any problems.

What I need to do is go though each table and import the data into a corresponding table on a SQL Server database. There is no transformation of the data, as the table structures are the same. All that needs to be done is the data in the SQL Server database must first be deleted and then the data from the Paradox tables inserted.

I can connect one table in Paradox to one table in SQL Server but I want to do them all, please tell me I don't need a separate data task for each

Thanks

Ken

Comment: Woah. You can connect SSIS 2012 to a Dox Box?

Comment: Oh yes you can have got the connection working with a single table. Just need to know how to do all the tables. I'm taking data from Paradox to SQL not the other way round.

Answer (score 0):

Try using a ForEach Loop Container to enumerate all the tables in your database.